# Conflicting targets during Qt6.4.1 build

Tags: qt, cmake, build

I'm trying to build qt from sources but it fails curing configure stage, saying about conflicting targets.

After cloning 6.4.1 branch from [official repo](https://github.com/qt/qt5), I tried to configure it using configure.bat from x64 Native Tools Command Prompt VS 2022

`c:\Qt\Qt6.4.1>configure -debug-and-release -prefix %CD%/qtbase -opensource -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests`

It prints such errors about different building targets:

```
...

CMake Error at build/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:2066 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create target "Bundled_Poly2Tri" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a static library
  created in source directory
  "C:/Qt/Qt6.4.1/qtlocation/src/3rdparty/poly2tri".  See documentation for
  policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/Qt3rdPartyLibraryHelpers.cmake:52 (_qt_internal_add_library)
  qtbase/cmake/Qt3rdPartyLibraryHelpers.cmake:163 (qt_internal_add_common_qt_library_helper)
  qtpositioning/src/3rdparty/poly2tri/CMakeLists.txt:7 (qt_internal_add_3rdparty_library)

...


CMake Error at build/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlMacros.cmake:329 (message):
  Output directory for target "PositioningQuick" is already used by another
  QML module (target "PositioningQuick").  Output directory is:

    C:/Qt/Qt6.4.1/build/qtbase/qml/QtPositioning


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt6Qml/Qt6QmlBuildInternals.cmake:317 (qt6_add_qml_module)
  qtpositioning/src/positioningquick/CMakeLists.txt:7 (qt_internal_add_qml_module)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Qt/Qt6.4.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Qt/Qt6.4.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error at C:/Qt/Qt6.4.1/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:965 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.
```

Edit:
I also tried 6.3 and Linux, same issue.

Comment: The example in [the github readme](https://github.com/qt/qt5#windows) uses `-refix %CD%\qtbase` for the configure script, and I think you are essentially using `-prefix %CD%`. Have you tried using `-prefix C:\Qt\Qt6.4.1\qtbase` to better align with the readme example? If so, what was the outcome? And is there a particular reason you are doing it differently than the readme?

Comment: @starball thanks for your reply, i've just tried it - same result

Comment: did you try it with a clean slate? Ex. delete everything and clone repo again, or delete all build artifacts and configure again?

Comment: @starball yes tried, qt5 however builds like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue on Debian 11 with Qt6.2.4 and Qt6.4.2.  I ended up disabling qtlocation with -skip qtlocation in the configure.